# Debugging Issue in visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a strange issue that my debugger hits the previous line in code again even it already has executed that line, and when it again executes that line which creates an exception? Why is this happening that debugger again hits the previous line, I am stuck at this point. 
This is screenshot of the code:
[image]
Line 1011 is hit for the first time but after client.Dispose() is called, it again calls client.Disconnect(true); line even the continue statement is hit. What could be the issue that is causing all this.

Comment: You most likely have a potential stack overflow, where one or two methods are calling each other. Did you override the Dispose method on the client's class? Maybe somewhere in that code you call the very same method again.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are giving as an example doesn't give a lot of information, though as far as I can tell, Dispose is calling the Disconnect method as well. Try and wrap the client object in a using statement, calling Disconnect at the end and .NET's garbage collector will take care of the rest.

The second call to Disconnect will now through an Exception as the object has been disposed.